# How to remove the red box in War Inc. Battlezone?

Tags: technical-issues, war-inc-battlezone

[image]I play War Inc. Battlezone on Steam and I have an issue with the weapons and other items being a red box instead of the actual image. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: If you would add a screenshot that shows your problem, we could help you better. It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Did you try to verify your game cache? https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335

Comment: thanks alot post it as an answer and I'll give u the reward

Comment: I don't think that such a trivial thing needs to be an answer

Comment: That did not work anything else?

Comment: Look into the settings of your graphics card if you enforced Antialiasing and see if disabling it helps, if you did.

Comment: Or if that didn't work then try to re-install the game, because it might have just been a falter in the install process?

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of graphical glich in a steam game is most likely caused by broken cache files. If there is any missing items (invisible items, colorful boxes appearing instead of the items etc ) then it is most likely it. On top of that your games might crash because of the corrupted cache.

Solution to this problem is described on the actual steam website and im usually not a fan of copy paste but i think in this case it make sure i dont skip out on any details.

Verify integrity of game cache

```
1. Load Steam
2. From the Library section, right-click on the game and select Properties from the menu.
3. Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game cache... button.
4. Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.
5. Once the process is completed, the Check Window will automatically exit.
```

Re-extract the Game Files for Valve games
Important:

This portion is only valid for Valve games stored in a specific user folder such as the Half-Life series, Orange Box, and Counter-Strike.

Once you have verified the integrity of your game cache files, you can make sure that your extracted game files are correct by navigating to your Steam user directory: ..\Steam\steamapps[USER NAME]\ and either renaming or deleting your game folder.

Note: If you are playing a Singleplayer game and wish to keep your saved games, rename the game directory.

The next time you run the game, it will re-extract the files from your game cache files. If you wish to restore your saved games, copy the SAVE folder from your old game directory to your new one.

Here is the [Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335).

Comment: i have already tried this and it did not work

Comment: alright ill look into it further.

Comment: Why has this answer been voted down ?

Comment: @SaadBen apparently he tired it already and it didnt work for him

Comment: @SaadBen Ya i tried twice and it failed. THats 12 hours of my gaming life gone.

Comment: A constructive answer that doesn't work is not supposed to be voted down. Don't forget it's also someone else's time used uniquely dedicated to trying to help you for free.

Comment: @SaadBen Just because you spent time on your answer, doesn't mean it's 'right'. The downvote arrow tooltip specifically reads "This answer is not useful". I apologize if you feel like your time was 'wasted' or isn't being appropriately rewarded, but someone felt your answer wasn't useful to them. They aren't wrong to downvote as a result, whether you like it or not. If others disagree, they can upvote it. That's how this whole wild and crazy Stack Exchange thing works.

Answer (score -1):

This problem seems to be caused by certain graphics cards and their lack of support for the way that the game renders bitmaps. Unfortunately, there is nothing that you can do to fix this aside from talking to the game's developers.

This was sourced from the War Inc. Battlezone forums whenever I had a similar problem. Those forums are currently down.